# ERROR displaying image while form is processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i need to display image when form is processing

And this following code works **problem is** when i press submit image is displayed but if there are some error in form filed the form will not process **but images is displayed**

How do i make images display when  user press submit button the image should appear only when form is processing

### CODE

```
<input onclick="showImg()" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
<img alt="" src="ajax-loader.gif" id="progress_img" style="visibility:hidden;">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function showImg()
   {
   if (document.getElementById) {
   (document.getElementById("progress_img")).style.visibility = "visible";
   }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: its `HTML` form with image upload and text field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have created a small demo. Check it out.

```js
var progressImg = document.getElementById('progress_img');
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

myForm.onsubmit = onFormSubmit;

function onFormSubmit() {
  var error = false;

  // Check for errors

  if (error) {
    // Show error messages
  } else {
    // Display the image
    progressImg.style.display = 'block';

    // Do your AJAX call
    // and hide the image when AJAX is completed
  }

  // This is to prevent the form from submitting
  return false;
}
```

```css
#progress_img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: none;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="#">
  <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
  <img id="progress_img" src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="">
</form>
```

If anything is not clear for you, feel free to ask me.

Comment: i don't get image in demo

Comment: i tried the above code in my script but loading image is visible before clicking submit i think i should assign image hidden in css ??

Comment: Yes, sure. Sorry I have forgotten that.

Comment: when i press submit button image is displayed but form is not processed

Comment: If you want to show a progress image during the form processing, you should use AJAX. I have commented in the code, where the AJAX call should be made. If you want to process the form without AJAX, the browser will refresh the whole page, so you can't show the progress image.

Comment: i need to process form and display image until page redirect

Comment: You have to use AJAX. Please read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: if you would make a simple demo using this it would be great

Comment: Here is a very simple example of making AJAX request with pure JavaScript: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully undestood what you are trying to do, but you could validate all the things you need using javascript.
The best way to achieve what you are willing is to change the button type to "button", not "submit" and then on the "onClick" "showImg()" function, replace it for the validations, then show the image, and then use the javascript submit function. I know it's easy with

```
 document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

Comment: Or have more control over it by submiting using ajax and listening for errors